Azure Devops REST API update agent userCapabilities
I want to use the Azure DevOps REST API to configure automatically post agent creation some user capabilities.
It seems there is a specific API for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#request-body
But after a bunch of tests and after reading other posts of other having similar issues (below references) I still can't add userCapabilities from API. Here's my bash script:
pat="[redacted_pat]"
org_name="[redacted_org_name]"
agent_name="[redacted_agent_name]"
pool_name="[redacted_pool_name]"
pool_base_url="https://dev.azure.com/$org_name/_apis/distributedtask/pools?poolName=$pool_name&api-version=7.1-preview.1"
response=$(curl -u :$pat $pool_base_url)
pool_id=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.value[].id')
agent_base_url="https://dev.azure.com/$org_name/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$pool_id/agents?agentName=$agent_name&api-version=7.1-preview.1"
response=$(curl -u :$pat $agent_base_url)
agent_id=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.value[].id')
body=$(cat <<EOF
{{"foo":"bar"},id: $agent_id} 
EOF
)
put_capability_base_url="https://dev.azure.com/$org_name/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$pool_id/agents/$agent_id?usercapabilities&api-version=5.0"
curl -X PUT -u :$pat -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "$body" $put_capability_base_url


the latest curl responds 200 OK and in the output it shows that it creates the user capability foo with value bar. But both a look in the UI and a Get call to the agent API show that no new capabilities have been added. In various test and try tentatives I implemented basically all the solution proposed below (put instead of patch, agent id in the body, endpoint with usercapabilities or not, etc.)
References:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/issue-of-api-to-update-the-usercapabilities/616954
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-agents-update-api-patch-requires-the/568004
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-agents-update-api-patch-not-working-f/567978

Is there someone out there that was able to solve this issue?

I have checked the bash script to run the Rest API to update the Agent userCapabilities.
You can change to use the following Rest API and Request Body:
Rest API:
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{pool id}/agents/{agent id}/usercapabilities?api-version=5.0

Request Body:
{"foo1":"bar","foo2":"bar"}

Here is the Bash script:
pat="pat"
org_name="orgname"
agent_name="agentname"
pool_name="agentpoolname"
pool_base_url="https://dev.azure.com/$org_name/_apis/distributedtask/pools?poolName=$pool_name&api-version=7.1-preview.1"
response=$(curl -u :$pat $pool_base_url)
pool_id=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.value[].id')
echo $pool_id
agent_base_url="https://dev.azure.com/$org_name/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$pool_id/agents?agentName=$agent_name&api-version=7.1-preview.1"
response=$(curl -u :$pat $agent_base_url)
agent_id=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.value[].id')

echo $agent_id
body=$(cat <<EOF
  {"foo1":"bar"}
EOF
)


put_capability_base_url="https://dev.azure.com/$org_name/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$pool_id/agents/$agent_id/usercapabilities?api-version=5.0"
curl -X PUT -u :$pat -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "$body" $put_capability_base_url

Result:


